# SQL Server Rights to backup drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to copy a backup I've made from one server to another using either an SSIS or Powershell step in a job.  I've run into the same error on both systems when running the step under the sql agent.  I receive errors that the path does not exist.  I've tried granting the agent rights to e:\backups, where the file is located, but it still doesn't work.

When I use a proxy for the step, it works fine.

Can anyone help me with what permissions to grant to sqlagent?

Rights look to have been granted to MSSQL$Instance1 on the backup drive.

Comment: Granted SQLAgent$Instance1 full rights to the e:\backups folder and still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you indicate you are copying to E:\Backups that it represents another server, it sounds like you are using mapped drives. Whatever agent you are using is probably being run in non-interactive logon mode, which precludes the use of mapped drives. 
I suggest you try to use UNC paths instead, ex: \\servername\backups

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify, but I am using UNC paths.